# How to detect Chrome extension uninstall

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to detect whether my extension was uninstalled.

I can't use `chrome.management.onUninstalled` because it will be fired on other extension.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Google Chrome, unlike Firefox, doesn’t allow to detect when the user uninstalls the extension, which is quite useful to understand user behaviour.
There is [a feature request on crbug.com](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=19383) with a discussion of this feature but it has not been implemented yet.

Comment: I think this is the one which is being discussed regarding uninstall of extension.

Comment: What i do is basically set up an event on blur for my orphaned content script to get a 1pixel image on interval and if the window is blured and it can't get the image it's because the extension isn't installed i then reload the page. It's jank but it works.

Comment: @btm1, Please re-explain.

Comment: If you are looking for this in 2023, there is an API now `setUninstallURL` - https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-setUninstallURL

Answer (score 31):

As of Chrome 41, you can now [open a URL when the extension is uninstalled](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-setUninstallURL). That could contain an exit survey or track the uninstall event as some sort of analytics.

Comment: It would be helpful if you highlighted that extension code still can't detect / react to being uninstalled.

Comment: You can send details of the user stored locally on the device as URL parameters. If you have a server, you can use this to send the details and track who has uninstalled

Answer (score 8):

You can call [`chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL("www.example.com/survey")`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-setUninstallURL) and redirect user to a url. Unfortunately, as soon as the extension is removed, the background script is removed too, and you can't do anything like log event or send hit to google analytics.

What I did is to set the redirect url to my server endpoint, and do some tasks like logging event to my own db, or sending hit to google analytics ([ga hit builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/)). Then call `res.status(301).redirect("www.example.com/survey")` to some survey url. Finally I can send the uninstall event to google analysis.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Manifest V3, you can add it on your onInstalled Listener. If you want to capture uninstall for existing users as well, you need to add it to 'update' as well.

Place this code in your background page:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (details) {
    if (details.reason == 'install') {
        ... can add things like sending a user to a tutorial page on your website
        chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL('https://www.yourwebsite.com/uninstall');
    } else if (details.reason == 'update') {
        ... can add things like sending user to a update page on your website
        chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL('https://www.yourwebsite.com/uninstall');
    }
});
```

Find more information here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-setUninstallURL

Answer (score 0):

##### Content Script can Detect an Uninstall

Simply check the value of `chrome.runtime`, which becomes `undefined` when an extension is uninstalled.

A good trigger to check this is port disconnect:

```js
// content_script.js

const port = chrome.runtime.connect();

port.onDisconnect.addListener(onPortDisconnect);

function onPortDisconnect() {
  // After the extension is disabled/uninstalled, `chrome.runtime` may take 
  // a few milliseconds to get cleared, so use a delay before checking.
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!chrome.runtime?.id) {
      console.log('Extension disabled!');
    }
  }, 1000);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

For mv3: An easy way would be to have

```
// Redirect users to a form when the extension is uninstalled.
const uninstallListener = (details) => {
  if (details.reason === chrome.runtime.OnInstalledReason.INSTALL) {
    chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL('https://forms.gle/...');
  }

  if (details.reason === chrome.runtime.OnInstalledReason.UPDATE) {
    // TODO: show changelog
  }
};
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(uninstallListener);
```

Place it in your background.