# chrome extension - inform content script about removed extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that injects content scripts to different web-pages. Is there a way to recognize (in these content scripts) the fact that the extension has been removed by the user?

I am looking for a more elegant solution than sending "ping" messages to the background script, if there is any.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792552/how-to-detect-chrome-extension-uninstall) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case a long-lived connection is established from the content-script to the background-script, then listeners of onDisconnect are called when the extension is removed.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#property-Port-onDisconnect

Answer (score 0):

I guess that nothing is the best solution to know that your extension is uninstalled as soon as possible in the content script. And, the way with the ping messages you mentioned is a better way, I think.

Well, if you have a backend Web server, your extension can send a request when the extension is uninstalled with [chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-setUninstallURL) API. You can append some session ID to the URL as query parameter or pathinfo, and the backend server can know the dead session ID. As the result, the content script can know whether the extension is uninstalled or not by the session state in the backend server.