# Feedback on uninstall of chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I recently made a chrome extension.
I see a lot of people uninstalling it in the stats.
I want to implement a feedback feature where if you uninstall it, I can at least know what the reason was.
Any idea how to create a quick popup in which they could give the feedback and it would directly go to my email. 
Link for the plugin if it matters: [Markit](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markit-text-highlighter-a/gppkdamjnjjjbfpiopekeccgaigakcng)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect Chrome extension uninstall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792552/how-to-detect-chrome-extension-uninstall)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you can do now is to call [`runtime.setUninstallURL`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-setUninstallURL) api, which means you can do your analysis in server side.

> Sets the URL to be visited upon uninstallation. This may be used to clean up server-side data, **do analytics**, and implement surveys.

Answer (score 4):

I'll post a complete code here as it took me some time to figure out how exactly to do that.

Put it in your background script or anywhere where you know it will be executed for sure. It just need to be run once:

```
/* Check whether new version is installed */
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
    /* other 'reason's include 'update' */
    if (details.reason == "install") {
        /* If first install, set uninstall URL */
        var uninstallUrlLink = 'https://example.com';
        /* If Chrome version supports it... */
        if (chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL) {
            chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL(uninstallUrlLink);
        }
    }
});
```

Taken from [this](http://shivankaul.com/blog/chrome-extension/2017/07/14/feedback-form-for-chrome-extensions.html) post